# SVI (VLAN issue) in Nexus 5548 VPC

Tags: vlan

I have an ongoing VLAN issue in my NX55 VPC. I'm new to the Nexus environment, so I need advice on this.

I've created 3 VLANs in a Nexus 5548 VPC (where all the gateways are in my Core 6500VSS) .

I do not have a L3 daughter card inside my NX55, but I have LAN_BASE_SERVICE_PKG license to activate the `interface-vlan` feature.

I've been advised that since I don't have a L3 daughter card, I will not be able to bring up L3 in my NX55, so I keep it as L2 while the routing will be handled by my Core 6500VSS with an Etherchannel VPC between them. Someone told me that having LAN_BASE license without L3 daughter card can cause issue on an SVI, so I already removed it, but the issue is still persists.

The strange thing is that only 2 of 3 VLANs are UP, though they are all set in the same configuration.

```
Vlan716 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is EtherSVI, address is  002a.6a3f.3681
  Description: VLAN-SVR716
  Internet Address is 172.27.16.2/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec
SZANDCSF01# sh int vlan 717
Vlan717 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is EtherSVI, address is  002a.6a3f.3681
  Description: VLAN-SVR717
  Internet Address is 172.27.17.2/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec
SZANDCSF01# sh int vlan 718
Vlan718 is down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is EtherSVI, address is  002a.6a3f.3681
  Description: VLAN-SVR718
  Internet Address is 172.27.18.2/23
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec
SZANDCSF01# ping 172.27.16.1 source 172.27.16.2
PING 172.27.16.1 (172.27.16.1) from 172.27.16.2: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.27.16.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=2.986 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.16.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=2.409 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.16.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=2.483 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.16.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=2.474 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.16.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=2.481 ms
--- 172.27.16.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.00% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.409/2.566/2.986 ms
SZANDCSF01# ping 172.27.17.1 source 172.27.17.2
PING 172.27.17.1 (172.27.17.1) from 172.27.17.2: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.27.17.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=2.979 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.17.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=2.413 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.17.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=2.481 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.17.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=2.485 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.17.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=2.477 ms
--- 172.27.17.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.00% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.413/2.567/2.979 ms
SZANDCSF01# ping 172.27.18.1 source 172.27.18.2
PING 172.27.18.1 (172.27.18.1) from 172.27.18.2: 56 data bytes
Request 0 timed out
Request 1 timed out
Request 2 timed out
Request 3 timed out
Request 4 timed out
--- 172.27.18.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.00% packet loss
```

In the `#sh vpc consistency-parameters global`, it says that my VLAN 718 is suspended.

```
1# sh vpc consistency-parameters global
    Legend:

Type 1 : vPC will be suspended in case of mismatch

 Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value
 -------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
 QoS                         2     ([], [3], [], [], [],  ([], [3], [], [], [],
                              [])                    [])
 Network QoS (MTU)           2     (1538, 2196, 0, 0, 0,  (1538, 2196, 0, 0, 0,
                              0)                     0)
 Network Qos (Pause)         2     (F, T, F, F, F, F)     (F, T, F, F, F, F)
 Input Queuing (Bandwidth)   2     (50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0)   (50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 Input Queuing (Absolute     2     (F, F, F, F, F, F)     (F, F, F, F, F, F)
 Priority)
 Output Queuing (Bandwidth)  2     (50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0)   (50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 Output Queuing (Absolute    2     (F, F, F, F, F, F)     (F, F, F, F, F, F)
 Priority)
 STP Mode                    1     Rapid-PVST             Rapid-PVST
 STP Disabled                1     None                   None
 STP MST Region Name         1     ""                     ""
 STP MST Region Revision     1     0                      0
 STP MST Region Instance to  1
  VLAN Mapping
 STP Loopguard               1     Disabled               Disabled
 STP Bridge Assurance        1     Enabled                Enabled
 STP Port Type, Edge         1     Normal, Disabled,      Normal, Disabled,
 BPDUFilter, Edge BPDUGuard        Disabled               Disabled
 STP MST Simulate PVST       1     Enabled                Enabled
 VTP domain                  2
 VTP version                 2     1                      1
 VTP mode                    2     Server                 Server
 VTP password                2
 VTP pruning status          2     Disabled               Disabled
 IGMP Snooping Group-Limit   2     4000                   4000
 Interface-vlan admin up     2     716-717                716-717
 Interface-vlan routing      2     1,716-717              1,716-717
 capability
 Allowed VLANs               -     1,716-717              1,716-718
 Local suspended VLANs       -     718                    -

     SZANDCSF01# sh int trunk vlan 718
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Port          Native  Status        Port
              Vlan                  Channel
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Port          Vlans Allowed on Trunk
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Port          Vlans Err-disabled on Trunk
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Eth1/9        none
     Eth1/10       none
     Eth1/17       718
     Eth1/18       718
     Po1           718
     Po20          none
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Port          STP Forwarding
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Eth1/9        none
     Eth1/10       none
     Eth1/17       none
     Eth1/18       none
     Po1           1,716-717
     Po20          1,716-718
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Port          Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Port          Vlans Forwarding on FabricPath
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SZANDCSF01# sh run int vlan 716

interface Vlan716
  no shutdown
  description VLAN-SVR716
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.27.16.2/24

interface Vlan717
  no shutdown
  description VLAN-SVR717
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.27.17.2/24

interface Vlan718
  no shutdown
  description VLAN-SVR718
  ip address 172.27.18.2/23

SZANDCSF02# sh run int vlan 716

interface Vlan716
  no shutdown
  description VLAN-SVR716
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.27.16.3/24

interface Vlan717
  no shutdown
  description VLAN-SVR717
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.27.17.3/24

interface Vlan718
  no shutdown
  description VLAN-SVR718
  ip address 172.27.18.3/23

SZANDCSF01# sh run int po 1

interface port-channel1
  description ** PEER-LINK TO SZANDCSF02 **
  switchport mode trunk
  spanning-tree port type network
  speed 10000
  vpc peer-link

SZANDCSF01# sh run int po20

interface port-channel20
  description **L2-ETHERCHANNEL TO SZANDCRL01** (Portchannel to Core 6500VSS)
  shutdown
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,716-718
  spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
  vpc 20

SZANDCSF02# sh run int po 1

interface port-channel1
  description ** PEER-LINK TO SZANDCSF01 **
  switchport mode trunk
  spanning-tree port type network
  speed 10000
  vpc peer-link

SZANDCSF02# sh run int po 20

interface port-channel20
  description **L2-ETHERCHANNEL TO SZANDCRL01**
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,716-718
  spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
  vpc 20
```

I don't know if I made mistakes in the configuration, but I hope you can help me on this.

Comment: Could you please post the configuration of the interfaces in question (on both sides) and the configuration of the respective port-channel interfaces?)

Comment: Do you have any interfaces assigned to VL 718?

Comment: This is the config of the Vlan in both NX55

Comment: I edit the config and put the config of Vlan and Portchannel.                         @Ron: no I don't have any interface assigned to Vlan 718, but neither 716 & 717 but they can ping each other.

Comment: i guess it is  inconsistency issue ,  output of `sh vpc consistency-parameters global` command secession `Allowed VLANs`and `Local suspended VLANs` are not the same

Comment: Try resetting the vlan (shut, no shut)

Comment: Why is your po2 interface shutdown on one side?